# Unit test to determine if a popup box was shown

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I am not sure how to assert that a help file (.chm) was shown by a method with a void return type?  The only thing I can think of is to check to see if any exception was thrown during the method, but that doesn't really verify the box was shown or not.

Does anyone know how to verify if a help file was shown?

Comment: I wouldn't call this unit test. In unit test, you'd mock dependencies of that method and make sure that appropriate actions were called.

Comment: Strictly speaking that's an integration test but still a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the existence of the hh.exe process after opening it.  This is the "Microsoft HTML Help Executable" process

Comment: May also want to grab the handles of any such existing processes before then exclude those when checking after.  There's still a small window where a new unrelated one could open up but the likelihood is small enough that it doesn't matter